# Помогите установить пакет tree на ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

Не могу установить  на виртуальной машине. Пакет tree на Ubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если сначала попробовать `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Какие репозитории у вас подключены? `apt-get update; apt-cache search tree`. На крайняк - отсюда возьмите пакет - http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tree

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

По умолчанию репозиторий, в котором располагается пакет `tree` отключен. Для его включения необходимо зайти в настройки и подключить репозиторий `universe`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого выполнить:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tree
```